# how do I fix choppy audio on 16.04 when I'm playing games?

Tags: sound

Sometimes when I boot up games I get really staticy and choppy audio. it even happens on youtube videos and with mp3's. sometimes it's like a feedback or delay in the audio. other times it just mangles the sound and I can't stand to listen to it.